# Highcharts Maps labels don't all show

Tags: highcharts, maps

Playing with the Highcharts Map samples and wanted to see how multiple series worked with maps. Here is the US population density map with another series showing the state capitals:

```
        $.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/us-capitals.json', function (dcap) {
            $.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/us-population-density.json', function (data) {
                // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
                $.each(data, function () {
                    this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
                });
                if (_dochartwhenready === true) {
                    if (_domap === true) {
                        var mapobject = {

                            chart: {
                                map: 'countries/us/us-all',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                renderTo: 'container'
                            },

                            title: {
                                text: 'US population density (/km²)'
                            },

                            exporting: {
                                sourceWidth: 600,
                                sourceHeight: 500
                            },

                            legend: {
                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
                                floating: true,
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                y: 25
                            },

                            mapNavigation: {
                                enabled: true
                            },

                            colorAxis: {
                                min: 1,
                                type: 'logarithmic',
                                minColor: '#EEEEFF',
                                maxColor: '#000022',
                                stops: [
                                    [0, '#EFEFFF'],
                                    [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                                    [1, '#000022']
                                ]
                            },

                            series: [{
                                animation: {
                                    duration: 1000
                                },
                                data: data,
                                joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                    format: '{point.code}'
                                },
                                name: 'Population density',
                                tooltip: {
                                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
                                }
                            },
                                {
                                    animation: {
                                        duration: 3000
                                    },
                                type: 'mappoint',
                                name: 'Cities',
                                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                                data: dcap,
                                joinBy: ['lat', 'lat', 'lon', 'lon'],
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled:true,
                                    color: '#ccccc',
                                    format: '{point.capital}'
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    pointFormat: '{point.capital}: {point.population}'
                                }

                            }]

                        };

                        _map = new Highcharts.Map(mapobject);

                    }
```

This works -- partly:

[image: Note only a few state capitals named]

The tool tips work exactly as expected. However, only a few state capital names show up on the map. How come?

Comment: Add live example

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem are overlapping **data labels**. This code forces Highcharts to show all of them:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vtwv061b/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap

Answer (score 1):

This is simply due the zoom level, aparently.
Also, I would not recomend using `joinBy` on lat and long since the may vary in really small decimals.

Here's a fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3ttmyxmo/

If you zoom in you will see the capital names popping over.

I used `joinBy` on postal-code and abrev instead of lat long:

```
{
    animation: {
        duration: 3000
    },
    type: 'mappoint',
    name: 'Cities',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
    data: capitals,
    joinBy: ['postal-code', 'abrev'],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled:true,
        color: '#ccccc',
        format: '{point.capital}'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{point.capital}: {point.population}'
    }
}
```